# Exit from SP mode on SUN FIR X2270

Tags: solaris-10, sun

i have sun fire x2270 , iam able to log in on sp mode and here i want to start my console mean i want the access of # mode.

-> cd /SP/console
/SP/console

-> start
Are you sure you want to start /SP/console (y/n)? y

Serial console started.  To stop, type ESC (

after the above message i am stuck ,how can i enter in # mode so that i can install some other applications etc.
waiting for response.

Regards
Shaukat